# How do I show hidden files in the Cloud Shell Editor file tree?

Tags: google-cloud-shell-editor

I am developing a vuepress with Cloud Shell Editor.

https://shell.cloud.google.com/

I need to edit the .vuepress/config.js, but I can not see it because it is a hidden folders. Does anybody knows how to show hidden folders/files in the Cloud Shell Editor file tree?

Answer (score 5):

In the cloud-shell editor menu bar go to view and select "Toggle Hidden Files" or using the shortcut Ctrl+I.

Comment: easy peasy lizard squeezy... after wasting soo many minutes... and then my director asks how is the cloud functions deployment going and I think how to explain I got stuck with finding my .gcloudignore file... thanks again.